# Is there a task widget that only shows todays tasks?

Tags: applications, app-widgets, task-management, to-do-list

Is there a task widget that only shows todays tasks?  I have a had  a few that I have downloaded, synced with my google account, and all was fine. I then added that task app as a widget and started completing tasks, and future tasks appear. For example, I have make;

Make coffee (due 1-11-12)
Make lunch (due 1-11-12)
Do laundry (due 1-11-12)
Make coffee (due 1-12-12)
Make lunch (due 1-12-12)

Now say I only see 3 tasks on the widget, so they all have a due date of 1-11-12. Great, all todays thing that need to be done, but as soon as I mark off make coffee, (due 1-11-12), it brings up make coffee (due 1-12-12), which I don't want. I only want to see todays tasks. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

If possible, I'd like the widget to be about the size of the calendar so it doesn't take up the entire screen. I'd like to keep the task and calendar on the same screen.

Answer (score 4):

## Try [Any.Do](http://www.any.do/).

It's an normal task app with nice style, and the widget is only showing tasks for today, also several sizes are available.

Answer (score 1):

[ColorNote's](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note&hl=en) "Today 2x2" widget will do this, but it unfortunately doesn't sync with Google tasks.

You can also do this using a combination of the [Pure Calendar Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.koxx.pure_calendar) (well worth the $1.99 for all the display options it gives you) and one of the many task applications it works with (I use [Dato GTasks](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.dayup.gtask), which syncs with Google Tasks). Just make sure to set the search period to 1 day in the calendar tab (you don't have to select a calendar, it works just fine with only a task service enabled).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Astrid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.timsu.astrid) for all my task/todo management.  It has a widget which is the exact same size as the calendar widget (2x2), and when you create it, you can choose to only include certain tasks using a variety of criteria, among which is tasks due today.

It's also open source, ad-free, and syncs with Google Tasks, as well as a couple others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in today's Calendar events I have had good results with Smooth Calendar. You can configure it to show only events in the next 24 hours.

If you are looking for an easy to use to do list application with widgets that show only Today's tasks, I recommend my app Maniana To List.

Both are free and ad free.